# Firefox doesn't run setInterval function (the latest Firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox, setinterval

I have simple code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        alert('Hello!');
    },3000);
});
```

This code working on Chrome, but doesn't work on Firefox o.O I using Firefox 28.0 and don't have any tips in FireBug (console is empty).

Comment: Have you included the jquery library?

Comment: Your code works in Firefox 28 for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jmVad/

Comment: Leo - thanks, so problem is in my code. Thanks so much. User3132718 - yes, if i haven't included jquery library then i will have bugs in console, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `load`

```
$(document).load(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        alert('Hello!');
    },3000);
});
```